# Ext JS changing CSS of a each item in the Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I m currently trying to change the style of my Panel like in the picture but i cant manipulate the css of every single item in the Panel. For an example, i tried to move the last textfield a little down from others and wanted to give a different width with style attribute, but somehow it doesn't work. 
Any ideas about how to do it ?

[image: what i m trying to do looks like this]

```
  Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.form.FieldTypes', {
    viewModel: true,
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'form-fieldtypes',
    renderTo:"tab3",
    layout: 'form',
    height: 565,
    width: 800,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield1',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        value: 'Text field value'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield2',
        fieldLabel: 'Description',
        value: 'Text field value'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield3',
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        value: 'Text field value'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield4',
        fieldLabel: 'Version',
        value: 'Text field value'
    },{
       xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield5',
        fieldLabel: 'Tag',
        value: 'Text field value',
        style:
                {
                       width:'20px',
                      'margin-top':'130px',
                },
    }]
})

Ext.create('form-fieldtypes', {
        renderTo: "tab3"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{
       xtype: 'textfield',
       name: 'textfield5',
       fieldLabel: 'Tag',
       value: 'Text field value',
       width: 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define extra cls attribute for panel.

and they write css classes for each item it will work.

or

you can also use baseCls attribute to override the styles of extjs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the configs directly on the textfield? May work better with the ExtJS Layouts.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'textfield5',
    fieldLabel: 'Tag',
    value: 'Text field value',
    margin: '130 0 0 0',
    width: 20
}
```

**EDIT**

I just realized you are using the form layout. I believe if you want to have control over the padding, margin, etc that you will have to use a different layout.